# Type 'void' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I run the below `post()` function, I'm getting the following error info:

```
Type 'void' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Here is what I'm trying to run:

```
  static async post(options:object) {
    const promise = postRequest(options)
    const [err, data] = await this.promiseWapper(promise);
    return [err, data]
  }

  static async promiseWapper(promise: any) {
    return
    promise()
      .then((res: any) => [undefined, res])
      .catch((err: any) => [err, undefined])
  }
```

How can I make this code run without errors?

Comment: This is not enough detail to give meaningful help. What does 'postRequest' do?

Comment: `promiseWrapper` is marked `async` but it's not `await`ing anything. Did you mean to `await` the result of that promise you're returning? Or maybe just remove the `async` keyword?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior while that's true, it's not necessarily a problem - async functions behave the same if they return a Promise. Any function that returns a promise without being marked async, will behave literally the same if you mark it async

Comment: @TKoL: So JavaScript will detect that you'd end up with a promise of a promise and unwraps it (or perhaps just avoids wrapping it in the first place)? That makes sense. It jives with the way `.then()` works. I'm used to async/await from C#, where you have to be more explicit about these things.

Comment: Your code has multiple problems: `promise` should not be called as a function, it should have type `Promise<any>` not any, you are not `return`ing anything from `promiseWrapper` (due to ASI) so it will have a `Promise<void>` return type, you should add return types to your functions instead of relying on type inference, your `promiseWrapper` that uses `.then()`/`.catch()` style should not be `async`.

Comment: Btw, don't use such a weird `promiseWrapper` at all. Just let your promises get rejected in case of an error. A tuple is no good representation for an optional result. Consider `[undefined, undefined]` - you can't even tell whether that's an error or not.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior yes, you can even do a simple test yourself. [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/yc18bvum/)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code. PromiseWrapper was calling promise as a FUNCTION, `promise()`, but it isn't a function, it's a promise. Assuming `postRequest` returns a promise, that is...

```
  async function post(options) {
    const promise = postRequest(options)
    const [err, data] = await this.promiseWapper(promise);
    return [err, data]
  }

  async function promiseWapper(promise) {
    return promise
      .then((res) => [undefined, res])
      .catch((err) => [err, undefined])
  }

  function postRequest() {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

  post();
```